# IndexError: tuple index out of range with write to txt file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have my code

```
import numpy as np

a1=np.empty(10)
a1.fill(1900)

a2=np.empty(10)
a2.fill(3100)

a3=np.empty(10)
a3.fill(3600)

with open('homes.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in a1:
        for j in a2:
            for k in a3:
               np.savetxt(f, i, j,k)
```

I want to write arrays to text file like this

```
1900. 3100. 3600. 
1900. 3100. 3600. 
1900. 3100. 3600.
```

But terminal gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "m84.py", line 16, in <module>
    np.savetxt(f, i, j,k)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1034, in savetxt
    ncol = X.shape[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

If my idea is wrong it would be nice that someone proposes other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by writing to the file normally:

```
with open('homes.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in a1:
        for j in a2:
           for k in a3:
               f.write("%f %f %f\n"%(i,j,k))
```

However, I am suspecting that you don't really want to do exactly this, because this will print 1000 lines (because of the nested loops). If you just want to write the arrays in a file, with each value being written once you can use `savetxt`, and you don't need to place it inside a loop. It can write a whole array at once, so you could do it as follows:

```
a = np.empty(shape = (10,3))
a[:,0].fill(1900)
a[:,1].fill(3100)
a[:,2].fill(3600)
np.savetxt("homes.txt",a)
```

Comment: Ok,it works but I got 100 lines in the file.How should I index the arrays a1[i]?

Comment: Edited, does it answer your question?

Comment: The above answer might solve your problem, I guess. But if you are tired of for loop inside for loop inside for, then you could use zip or similar build-in tools to make things simpler (depends on person to person). `f.write("\n".join(["%d %d %d" %(i, j, k) for i, j, k in zip(a1, a2, a3)]))`

Comment: `zip` is not equivalent here.